# send xml message through soap based ws in java

Tags: java, xml, soap, wsdl

I am a newbie in soap and web services . Basically I want to send xml message through soap based web service. Can anyone help me get started.
Any help regarding what API should I use would help.

Comment: first try your best.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately [questions asking for: books, libraries, tutorials, tools are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Comment: @poorna any help of what API to use in java would really help